# Find the next nearest value (bash)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

Let's say I have some holiday data (holiday_master.csv) in columns, something like

```
...
20200320   Vernal Equinox Day
20200429   Showa Day
20200503   Constitution Day
20200505   Green Day
20200720   Children's Day
20200811   Sea Day
...
```

Given this set of data, I want to find the next closest holiday from the given date.
For example if the input is `20200420`, `20200429   Showa Day` is expected.
If the input is `20200620`, `20200720   Children's Day` is expected.
I have a feeling that awk has the necessary functionality to do this, but any solution that works in a bash script is welcome.

Comment: How would you like to handle the case of two events occurring on the same date?

Comment: Thank you very much for your swift reply. I have made a correction on the table given so there will be no same date in the data.

Answer (score 3):

Would you please try the `bash` script:

```
#!/bin/bash

input="20200428"                        # or assign to whatever
< "holiday_master.csv" sort -nk1,1 |    # sort the csv file by date and pass to the while loop
while read -r date desc; do
    if (( date >= input )); then        # if the date is greater than or equal to the input
        echo "$date" "$desc"            # then print the line
        break                           # and exit the loop
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your code is really helpful in solving my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no two days will ever have the same date...

```
DATE=<some desired input date>
awk "{print (\$1 - $DATE"' "\t" $0)}' calendar.txt | sed '/^-/d' | sort | head -n 1 | awk '{$1=""; print $0}'
```

### Explanation

1. `awk "{print (\$1 - $DATE"' "\t" $0)}' calendar.txt`: Prepend a column to the *input.txt* file describing the difference between the **desired input date** and the date column
2. `sed '/^-/d'`: Remove all lines beginning with `-`. Dates with negative differences have already passed.
3. `sort`: Sort the remaining entries from least to greatest (based upon the difference column)
4. `head -n 1`: Select only the first row (The lowest difference)
5. `awk '{$1=""; print $0}'`: Print all but the first column

### Prettier script version

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# Usage: script <Date> <Calendar file>
DATE=${1:--1}
CAL=${2:-calendar.txt}

# Arg check and execute
if[ ! -f $CAL ]
then
    echo "File not found: $CAL"
    echo "Usage: script <Date> <Calendar file>"
elif [ $DATE -le 0 ]
then
    echo "Invalid date: $DATE"
    echo "Usage: script <Date> <Calendar file>"
elif [ $(echo "$DATE" | grep -Ewo -- '-?[0-9]+' | wc -l) -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "Invalid date: $DATE"
    echo "Usage: script <Date> <Calendar file>"
else
    awk '{print ($1 - '"$DATE"' "\t" $0)}' $CAL | sed '/^-/d' | sort | head -n 1 | awk '{$1=""; print $0}'
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

As you use YYYYMMDD format we might compare it just like numbers (note: year is greater than month, month is greater than day). So you can use `AWK` following way, let:

```
20200320   Vernal Equinox Day
20200429   Showa Day
20200503   Constitution Day
20200505   Green Day
20200720   Children's Day
20200811   Sea Day
```

be file named `holidays.txt` then:

```
awk 'BEGIN{inputdate=20200420}{if($1>inputdate){print $2;exit}}' holidays.txt
```

output:

```
Showa
```

Explanation: in `BEGIN` I set `inputdate` to `20200420` then when line with greater number in `1`st column is found I `print` content of `2`nd column and `exit` (otherwise later dates would be printed too). Note that `AWK` does automatically parse number when asked to do comparison (`>` in this case) so you do not have to care about conversion yourself - you could even do `inputdate="20200420"` and it would work too.

This solution assumes that all dates in file are already sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk and assuming the source data is comma separated:

```
awk -F, -v dayte="20200420" '
                        BEGIN {
                               "date -d "dayte" +%s" | getline dat1                                 
                              { 
                              {
                               "date -d "$1" +%s" | getline dat2;
                               dat3=dat2-dat1;
                               if (dat3 > 0 ) 
                                             { 
                                               hols[dat3]=$2 
                                             } 
                                } 
                          END { 
                                asorti(hols,hols1,"@ind_num_asc");
                                print hols[hols1[1]] 
                               }
                          ' holiday_master.csv
```

One liner:

```
awk -F, -v dayte="20200420" 'BEGIN { "date -d "dayte" +%s" | getline dat1 } { "date -d "$1" +%s" | getline dat2;dat3=dat2-dat1;if (dat3 > 0 ) { hols[dat3]=$2 } } END { asorti(hols,hols1,"@ind_num_asc");print hols[hols1[1]] }' holiday_master.csv
```

Set the field separator to , and set a variable dayte to the date we wish to check. In the BEGIN block, we pass the dayte variable through to date command via an awk pipe/getline and read the epoch result into the variable dat1. We do the same with the first column on the master file ($1) and read this into dat2. We take the difference between the epoch dates and read the result into dat3. Only if the result is positive (in the future) do we then use dat3 for an index in a "hols" array, with the holiday description as the value. In the END block, we sort the indexes of hols into a news hols1 array basing the sort on ascending, numeric indexes. We then take the first index of the new hols1 array to attain the holiday that is closest to the dayte variable.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the holiday list file is sorted by date as you have given, the below would work

```
$ awk  -v dt="20200420" ' (dt-$1)<0 { print;exit }  ' holiday.txt
20200429   Showa Day

$ awk  -v dt="20200620" ' (dt-$1)<0 { print;exit }  ' holiday.txt
20200720   Children's Day

$
```

If the holiday file is not sorted, then you can use below

```
$ shuf holiday.txt | awk  -v dt="20200420" ' dt-$1<0 { a[(dt-$1)*-1]=$0 } END { asort(a); print a[1] }  '
20200429   Showa Day

$ shuf holiday.txt | awk  -v dt="20200620" ' dt-$1<0 { a[(dt-$1)*-1]=$0 } END { asort(a); print a[1] }  '
20200720   Children's Day
```